# Java sound control not working

Tags: java, audio, javasound

My Java sound-play starts with error but does not play sound.

I've searched the web but it still doesn't work D:

can you please help me understand my problem + fix?

if you need any more details, code, dumps, outputs, data just let me know.

Sound.java:

```
package com.itaysharon.questematic;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;

import com.itaysharon.questematic.enums.SoundOptions;

public class Sound {

public static Thread dj;

public static synchronized void playSound(final String url, SoundOptions mode) {
    dj = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("assets" + File.separator + url));
                AudioSystem.getClip().open(inputStream);
                AudioSystem.getClip().setFramePosition(0);
                switch(mode) {
                    case Stop:
                        AudioSystem.getClip().stop();
                        break;
                    case Play:
                        AudioSystem.getClip().start();
                        break;
                    case Loop:
                        AudioSystem.getClip().loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
                        break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    if (mode != SoundOptions.Stop) {
        dj.start();
    } else {
        try {
            AudioSystem.getClip().stop();
            AudioSystem.getClip().close();
            dj.interrupt();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
}
```

SoundOptions.java:

```
package com.itaysharon.questematic.enums;

public enum SoundOptions {
    Play, Loop, Stop;
}
```

Comment: you could please share the error message

Comment: there is no error message, it just doesn't play the wav file

Comment: pure java and no special libs

Comment: the funny part is that it worked before with the same wav file...

Comment: yep and I tried on linux... same error

Comment: I have fix it for you

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ where is the fix? can you show it in an answer please?

Comment: It's for a game, TL;DR it is that you can "loop" (for bg music) the music or play it on runtime (without changing the code)

Comment: I don't have real music yet, I'm using an annoying 2 seconds wav file for testing, I guess 1 min - 5 mins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK after checking your code, there was quite small things here and there.

Before I start, maybe your code has worked coincidentally once previously and stopped working afterwards, this is typically when thread is not well programmed.

The problem is that the thread starts and ends before the audio file get the chance to play, because the thread does not know how long the file is in this case.

And since I do not have the full logic of how your program behaves, I will keep your code logic and added some few things that solves the problem as an isolated instance. Btw, I have tested the fixed the code and it works great as isolated class in my machine.

I would mentioned the key points for the solution. It is about letting the  thread continue with the audio playing time, till it is ended by the listener.

```
audioLineClip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
    @Override
    public void update(LineEvent event) {
        ... listen when audio is ended and close the line. to end the program.
    }
});
```

and we keep our thread waiting till audio is ended

```
synchronized (dj) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            dj.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You could theoretically use `Thread.sleep(sometime)` alone without synchronized, but since you do not know how long to sleep as you do not know how long the audio file is!

So your final code would look like this, I have put the solution in the code with explanation including extra minor changes with notes:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.File;

/**
 * By Maytham on 07-10-2016.
 */
public class Sound {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        playSound("8k16bitpcm.wav", SoundOptions.Play);
    }

    // 1) make it private
    private static Thread dj;

    // 2) make it private and 3) SoundOptions should be final
    private static synchronized void playSound(final String url, final SoundOptions mode) {
        dj = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
                            new File("assets" + File.separator + url));

                    // 4) declare AudioSystem in stead of using AudioSystem repeatedly
                    final Clip audioLineClip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(
                            new Line.Info(Clip.class));
                    audioLineClip.open(inputStream);
                    audioLineClip.setFramePosition(0);

                    // 5) our line listener checks when audio is ended and stops the line
                    //this is full example, but you manipulated your way
                    audioLineClip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void update(LineEvent event) {
                            LineEvent.Type type = event.getType();
                            if (type == LineEvent.Type.OPEN) {
                            } else if (type == LineEvent.Type.CLOSE) {
                                System.exit(0);
                            } else if (type == LineEvent.Type.START) {
                            } else if (type == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
                                audioLineClip.close();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    switch (mode) {
                        case Stop:
                            audioLineClip.stop();
                            break;
                        case Play:
                            audioLineClip.start();
                            break;
                        case Loop:
                            audioLineClip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
                            break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        if (mode != SoundOptions.Stop) {
            dj.start();

            // 6) this keep the thread until some line listener change status
            synchronized (dj) {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        dj.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {
            dj.interrupt();

            // 7) you do not need this it is done by line listener
            /*try {
                AudioSystem.getClip().stop();
                AudioSystem.getClip().close();
                dj.interrupt();
            } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does the playSound method have to be private? I'm calling it from another class

Comment: ok then you can make it protected or public depending on your structure

Comment: the thread is a great thing but if we do not use them correctly we can get crazy, and it is a world and art for its selves

Comment: the fixed code is working on my isolated debug class but not on the "generator"... I have to refactor my code :(

Comment: :) this is programmers life